# Can I make an NFC Tag reuse the same tab that is already open

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nfc

My company will soon put some NFC Tags on some products of ours, which contain a link to a website, where our customers can buy accessories which fit exactly to the product where they scanned the NFC Tag.

Most of the time, the customer will probably only scan one NFC Tag and buy accessories for this product.

It could be though, that they scan multiple products successively. My Problem is, that each time they scan a tag, a new tab in the browser will be created.

Is there any way to tell the NFC Tag in our web-application that there's already a website open with the same URL that is on the Tag and that it should just reuse this tab?

We have no control over the NFC Tag, we only have control of the web-application.

Some examples for URLs:

https://www.example.com/tag/TZ8JL0PO99CDFG42

https://www.example.com/tag/MFOT9NVDKROMLGF

https://www.example.com/tag/47HGFTNJNFO38NFR

My guess is that I can't do what I want and I have to live with the new tabs.

Additional Information: On the NFC-Tag, there's also a QR-Code if someone has a NFC-incompatible device (iPad e.g). The QR-Code should also be able to reuse a tab in the browser

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered storing state in the Session Storage on the device. When the urls are opened in different tabs, you could use the state from Session Storage to initialize the application, then transition to the new desired state.

Comment: I think the problem here (as I have a similar one) is the convenience: each card tap produces a new browser tab. In a short while, the browser is polluted with discarded tabs and the user gets annoyed. It's fairly easy to sync the tabs to stay up to date, but what about _not_ polluting the tab space?